# Android Downloading several Pages

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, download

I have a problem. When I click a button I have to download a main page from a website (the source). Then I have to parse the source to get other links from it. After that I have to add as many rows to my list view as I have found links in the main page source. And finally I have to download each link (the source again) and parse them. During the downloading / parsing I have to update my list view (the progressbar for example) with the information I get from these sources.

**But how do I do that?**

I thought I could just create two classes which both extends the `AsyncTask`. A `MainPageDownloader` and a `PageDownloader`. The `MainPageDownloader` would be started on button click. It downloads the main page and in the onPostExecute method it will parse the source and add the rows to the list. And then it will start the PageDownloaders.

I tried that but the `PageDownloaders` will start when the list has not even been updated yet. So I cannot update the `ProgressBar`'s in each row.

What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a whole different and better way?

Here are the two classes :

```
public class MainPageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream in = null;
        final int BUFSIZE = 1024;
        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL( params[0] );
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

            con.connect();
            in = con.getInputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            while (in.read(data) != -1) {
                result += new String(data);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cancel(true);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        List<String> links = new PageParser(result).getPageLinks();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        int rows = listView.getChildCount();

        //Add items & update list
        for( int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++ )
            adapter.add( new Item() );

        for( int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++ ){
            new PageDownloader(rows+i).execute("http://www.mylink.com/" + links.get(i) );
        }

    }



}


public class PageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    ProgressBar p;
    int row;

    public PageDownloader(int row) {
        //p is null, I have to comment it out or the program will crash
        //p = (ProgressBar) listView.getChildAt( row ).findViewById( R.id.progressBar1 );
        this.row = row;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream in = null;
        final int BUFSIZE = 1024;
        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL( params[0] );
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

            con.connect();
            in = con.getInputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            while (in.read(data) != -1) {
                result += new String(data);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cancel(true);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        PageParser parser = new PageParser( result );

        //Somehow the list is updated now and the titles will change
        listItems.get(row).setTitle( parser.getTitle() );
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //Not Possible because p is always null
        //p.setVisibility( ListView.GONE ); 
    }



}
```

Comment: Are you starting with a listview that has already items?

Comment: What is the connection between `listItems` and `adapter`?

Comment: @greenapps listItems is an arrayList which holds the data for the adapter.

Comment: You could only start a PageDownloader in the getView method of your adapter. Like a kind of lazy image loading. But now for title and description.